# Can I delete a city from my world?

Tags: cities-xl, cities-xl-2012

I've started a few cities while I was still learning the ropes. Can I completely delete them and reset their maps for later use, or am I stuck with them now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out three ways to do this:

- The first method is to delete the game's data folder ("Focus Home Interactive" in your local App Data folder.) This will delete all of your game's cities, and probably everything else you've done.
- The second method is to first load your city, then click the XL Menu and select Saves. Here you can load any of your old saves or select "Start over" to make a new city on the original landscape. (Note that this can't actually delete the city, since an empty city will be created.)
- The third option is to select "Load" from the planet screen, rather than loading a city directly from the top bar, then click "Delete" on the city tile you would like to delete.